# Linq Key that contains only the first of each duplicate

Tags: c#, excel, linq, dictionary

have to cast a list to a dictionary in my app but im getting an error saying that "An item with the same key has already been added". **I need first key** and his value

```
 Dictionary<string, string> cells = 
             (from cell in sheet.Cells["A1:J20"] 
             where cell.Start.Column == 1  && cell.Value != null
             select sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, 1, cell.Start.Row,9].Value)
             .Cast<object[,]>()
             .Distinct().ToDictionary(k => Convert.ToString(k[0, 2]), v => 
             Convert.ToString((v[0, 8])));
```

Example Excel:

- **kEY**   => **Value**
- Key1   =>   Value1
- Key2   =>   Value2
- Key3 => Value3
- Key3 => Value4
- Key3 => Value5
- Key6 => Value6
- Key7 => Value7
- Key23 => Value8

**EDIT**

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    var cells = (from cell in sheet.Cells["A1:B16"]
                                 where cell.Start.Column == 1 && cell.Value != null
                                 select sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, cell.Start.Column, cell.Start.Row, 2].Value)
                                                        .Cast<object[,]>();
```

cycle and add to dictionary:

```
  foreach (var i in cells) {
                        if (dict.ContainsKey(Convert.ToString(i[0, 0])) == false)
                            dict.Add(Convert.ToString(i[0, 0]), Convert.ToString(i[0, 1]));
                        // dict.Distinct();

                    }
```

**but i need code in linq!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide my problem

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = (from cell in sheet.Cells["A1:B34"]
                                 where cell.Start.Column == 1 && cell.Value != null
                                 select sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, cell.Start.Column, cell.Start.Row, 2].Value)
                                                        .Cast<object[,]>()
                                                        .GroupBy(k => Convert.ToString(k[0,0]))
                                                        .Select(k =>  k.First())
                                                        .ToDictionary(k => Convert.ToString(k[0, 0]), v => Convert.ToString(v[0, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning: untested code, I couldn't create a test environment easily:

```
Dictionary<string, string> cells = 
         (from cell in sheet.Cells["A1:J1"] 
         where cell.Value != null
         let key = sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, 3].Value.ToString()
         let val = sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, 9].Value.ToString()
         group val by key into vg
         select new { vg.Key, Val = vg.FirstOrDefault() })
         .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Val);
```

Also, optimized out a lot that seemed questionable to me.

Comment: What are you using to get Linq to sheet.Cells[] (Excel.Range object?) to work? When I setup Excel.Interop, I can't use Linq with Range objects.

Comment: I also don't see standard Excel Interop including Start.Column or Start.Row?

Comment: Okay, I think I fixed an error in the group by syntax. Also added ToString on the Key/Val as standard Interop appears to return Object a lot.